# C code appears to misplace values read with fscanf

Tags: c, variables, variable-assignment, scanf

I wrote a C program that is behaving in a way I don't understand. I am posting this in the hope that I will learn a bit more about C. The code seems to be writing variable names into other variables using fscanf when that was not asked of it at all...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
float BCL[6];
float varsRA[23],varsLA[23],varsBB[23],varsPV[23];  
FILE *inputfil;
int i;

inputfil = fopen ("file.txt", "rt");        
for(i=0;i<24;i++) {
    fscanf(inputfil,"%f %f %f %f\n", &(varsRA[i]), &(varsLA[i]), &(varsBB[i]), &(varsPV[i]));
}

i=23;
printf("vars%d:%f %f %f %f\n",i,varsRA[i], varsLA[i], varsBB[i], varsPV[i]);

i=0;
while(!feof(inputfil)) {
    fscanf(inputfil,"%f ",&(BCL[i]));
    i++;
}

i=23;
printf("vars%d:%f %f %f %f\n",i,varsRA[i], varsLA[i], varsBB[i], varsPV[i]);

fclose(inputfil);
return 0;
}
```

The outcome is:

```
vars23:-66.336823 -68.164223 -57.850136 -60.762585
vars23:-66.336823 -68.164223 -57.850136 177.000000
```

Why was the last value of varsPV changed to 177, which is the first value of BCL, when I read the rest of the file?!

Many thanks for your help,
Marta

Answer (score 3):

The program has undefined behaviour as it is accessing beyond the bounds of the arrays:

```
for(i=0;i<24;i++) {
    fscanf(inputfil,"%f %f %f %f\n", &(varsRA[i]), &(varsLA[i]), &(varsBB[i]), &(varsPV[i]));
}
```

Array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the number of elements in the array.
The arrays are defined with 23 elements, meaning valid indexes are from `0` to `22`. Change the loop terminating condition to `i < 23` or use a compile time constant to define the array size and the terminating condition to avoid duplicating that piece of information.

There are other out of bounds accesses in the program and this loop needs protection from going out of bounds:

```
i=0;
while(!feof(inputfil)) {              /* i < 6 required */
    fscanf(inputfil,"%f ",&(BCL[i]));
    i++;
}
```

Always check the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure assignments were actually made. `fscanf()` returns the number of assignments made:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6 && 1 == fscanf(input, "%f", &BCL[i]); i++);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays aren't being defined big enough. The array `varsRA[23]` only contains 23 elements numbered `0` through `22`. You're reading in *24* elements numbered `0` through `23`. Change your array definitions to the following and you should be good to go.

```
float varsRA[24],varsLA[24],varsBB[24],varsPV[24];
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices in C are zero-based.

```
float varsRA[23],varsLA[23],varsBB[23],varsPV[23]
```

Those arrays have 22 as their *last valid index*, which makes 23 elements. That's why

```
for(i=0;i<24;i++)
```

writes one extra element to each of them. What you get is undefined behavior (so there is nothing reasonable to expect), but your particual kind of undefined behavior is overwriting a piece of another array (and probably some random memory location).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I am used to Matlab now and the zero-indexing of C always throws me...